# What's the most straightforward way to plot a real time graph in python?

Tags: python, python-2.7, plot

I have some code that reads serial input from a current and a voltage sensor. I would like to make a 10s long graph of the voltage/current variation. What is the best way to do it? Ideally I would like 3 separate plots for voltage, current and power. This is what I've got so far:

```
data = [[],[],[]] # measurement number/V/I
plot_data = [[],[],[],[]] #measurement number/V/I/measurement time 

while (True):
    try:
        updateData()
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    print "Bye"
    saveCurrent()
    ser.close()
    sys.exit()
```

The array that is called plot data is 100 long so has the values that I want to plot live.

Comment: It would be important to know your target platform (Linux/Windows), for a better advice on a graphical library, anyway, you can use matplotlib from tkinter, check http://matplotlib.org/examples/user_interfaces/embedding_in_tk.html -

Comment: OSX, but writing this on a linux machine